# How to implement - share via mail with the right to choose?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, browser

I have a project where one of the points to share is - to share by e-mail (by sending). Most sites use

```html
<a href="mailto:<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send email</a>
```

But in this case, the sending is realized through the mail program (and not all users have it). The customer requires to implement this function with the ability to reach the audience as much as possible.
The solution is to give a choice to the client, when they click on the button, share. If there is a mail program, then we send it in this way (using - mailto :), if not, then we form a letter (using, for example, the PHP mail () function, the SMTPmail plugin, with the limitation of sending letters in time to reduce spam).
The main problem is how to determine (without involving the user) whether the user has a mail program on the computer. I'm a beginner in this business, but I feel that the main implementation problem is in the cross-platform plane.
Help solve this issue. Perhaps there are other, not known to me, ways of implementation - the choice in this case.

Comment: I think that every device has built in email program. There cannot be a situation when nothing will happen when he clicks on the link, even if the user is on mobile right? Or maybe you can just add this link and add information below like "or send us email on someone@example.com" so like text information for the user if he just wants to copy email address and send it directly from his program or something

Comment: `the mail program (and not all users have it).`...theoretically this could be possible but as sowam says it's probably very rare, although maybe on a pc it wouldn't be configured if the person mainly uses webmail. So yeah just make sure the email address is visible as text on the page so someone can copy it if they need to.

Comment: `The main problem is how to determine (without involving the user) whether the user has a mail program on the computer`...you can't. Your web page, running inside the browser, does not have access to that information. That's done for security/privacy reasons. There is no way to get round that.

Comment: Thank you. Here, in general, the essence of the problem and its solution are described  -https://adamsilver.io/blog/the-trouble-with-mailto-email-links-and-what-to-do-instead/